Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 won't compile my custom keyboard layout
I'm trying to compile a custom keyboard layout in MSKLC. It gives me a long list of validation warnings, which I know you should be able to just ignore (there are no relevant ones). Then, it gives me the error:

There was a problem building the keyboard file. Would you like to see warning/error information?

If I answer Yes, it tells me There were no warnings or errors., I can press OK, and it gives me the same error 3 more times. I have already re-installed MSKLC to C:\MSKLC and I'm a bit lost as to what to do next.
Is there another way to somehow convert a .klc file to an installer?

Check that your name and description aren't the same as already installed keyboards, and that there is no punctuations or anything in the names. Sometimes that fixes it.
